# how can I delete a gmail.com account?

Tags: gmail

I had a gmail.com address in my name a few minutes ago.  I tried to help a friend set up a gmail account in his name, but used my computer.  Now when I try to log in to my gmail account, only his shows up and mine seems to have been bumped off the internet.   How do I remove his gmail account from my computer and get mine back?

Comment: Did you log off his account?

Comment: Sign out from your friend's gmail account .

Answer (score 7):

Please check whether you follow the steps.

**1) Log out** from the gmail account that you are currently log in with. 
check the image. Do click on `Sign Out` from the menu of the upper right corner of your gmail.

[image: sign out]

**2)** then **Sign In agin** with `your Own USERNAME and PASSWORD` to gmail. Then you should be able to use your gmail account.

Even if you do the step 1 and at Step 2 , you still seeing your friend's gmail account, then Do the step 3.

**3) Clear your cache**.

If you are using Chrome Browser, do follow [this](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95582).

If you are using Firefox Browser, do follow [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cache-delete-temporary-files-fix-issues).

Now if you do the step 2 again, surely able to log in with your own account.

Hope this helps.